# How to prevent another login dialog with downloading Word,Excel document over Apache server with Basic Auth?

Tags: apache, ms-office

I have a front-end apache server running in a windows server.
The system is setup with NTLM or BASIC Auth (same problem with both).
A download from a MS Word or Excel documents works fine in all browsers.

If I use the Internet-Explorer and download a office document the download the document request another url.
Watchging the apache access logs I saw that there are requests with OPTIONS and PROPFIND inside.

So I modified the config using this:

```
  <Location /latest>
    <Limit OPTIONS PROPFIND>
      deny from all
    </Limit>
  </Location>
```

This worked so far, but with Office 2010 I encountered the problem again.

Searching the web I found this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019105
Therefor I don't have to send 403 (deny from all sends 403 I guess?), so I have to send 405.

So may I just do this? Is this correct?

```
  <Location /latest>
    <Limit OPTIONS PROPFIND>
      redirect 405
    </Limit>
  </Location>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally debugging more the issue I found out that this is the correct configuration.
To mention I have to make also clear that I sometimes setup the authentication in the background webserver (IIS 7) and sometimes inside the Apache (depends on customer situation).

1.
As Apache is my frontend proxy and the backend server is the IIS7, when IIS7 authenticate this worked:

---

Disable support of the OPTIONS and PROPFIND verbs – If the web application is not intended to be used for WebDAV, the Web Service Extension that provides the WebDAV functionality can be set to Prohibited on a default server that is running IIS. (This might be WebDAV or FrontPage Server Extensions.) If the site provides WebDAV functionality through another extension, the provider of that extension should be involved. For example, to do this with Windows SharePoint Services (WSS), the site should be configured to disable Client Integration, or the OPTIONS and PROPFIND verb should be inhibited. (On IIS 6, remove the verbs from the  registration line in the web.config file. On IIS 7.0, use the HTTP Verbs tab of the Request Filtering feature to deny the verbs.) Be aware that this approach will open the content in read-only mode because this approach disables direct-edit functionality.

---

from: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019105/en-us

So I set the content filter for the verbs and then it worked fine for me finally.

2.
Then I tested using the NTLM Auth in Apache.
My original config worked fine when Apache authenticate itself.

So I ran only into the problem mixing the behaviours :)

** EDIT **
For IIS web.config this should work:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <verbs applyToWebDAV="false">
        <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="false"/>
        <add verb="PROPFIND" allowed="false"/>
      </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I am facing similar problems but I have IIS and not Apache. Trying to find the equivalent of the same in IIS web.config. Anyone?

Comment: Found an older post, maybe this helps you: http://forums.iis.net/t/1172529.aspx?How+to+selectively+disable+PROPFIND+method+in+IIS+v6+0 . They key is UrlScan it seems to filter PROPFIND keyword. So it should be the sam eon IIS7 ff.

Comment: I can deny OPTIONS and PROPFIND with the config file but the server responds with a 404 status code for the PROPFIND and I get the authentication dialog... and yes I am using Office 2010 as in ur case

Comment: Do you have a web.config file in your project? I modified my answer and add a sample config.